# Websocket event listener locked when executing another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, websocket

I programmed an API in the lastest version of NodeJS.
Its goal was to have a RESTful interface where the user could send code
and a Websocket interface that the code can use

The only problem is that **i can't manage to run the event listener `client.on('data'` at the same time as my RESTful method.**

So if i do

```
global.writeRequest("#get_pos 1") // will request data from my Websocket Server and respond within 10ms~
Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, 4000); // wait 4 second to make sure the latency of the request doesn't affect the result
console.log("this is a test");
```

The request gets displayed last even though it should be displayed first.

Result of this command:

```
this is a test // our console.log
POST /api/data 200 2.373ms -12 // end of the RESTful Method
Server says: %pos[1]:488 // result of our global.writeRequest from earlier except it's shown at the end
```

Even weirder is that the event listener seems to be locked down during the whole RESTful method which is a problem considering i want to send and use the data coming from my event listener.

Even weirder is that when i do multiple `global.writeRequest` in one method like this:

```
global.writeRequest("#get_pos 1")
global.writeRequest("#get_pos 2")
global.writeRequest("#get_pos 3") // will request data from my Websocket Server and respond within 10ms~
Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, 4000); // wait 4 second to make sure the latency of the request doesn't affect the result
console.log("this is a test");
```

i end up with the following

```
this is a test // our console.log
POST /api/data 200 2.373ms -12 // end of the RESTful Method
Server says: %pos[1]:488%pos[2]:488%pos[3]:488
```

But it should display the following instead befoore the `console.log`:

```
Server says: %pos[1]:488
Server says: %pos[2]:488
Server says: %pos[3]:488
```

So i theorised that the event listener was locked when i executed another function so i tried to put all the functions in `async` but i got the same issue.

**The code:**

client_websocket.js

```
const net = require('net');
const client = new net.Socket();
const port = 50000;
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const password = "something";

client.connect(port, host, async function () {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(password);
});

client.on('close', async function () {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

writeRequest = async function (commmand) {
    client.write(commmand);
    return "Command sent!"
};
client.on('data', async function (data) {
    console.log("Server says: " + data);
}
```

requests_api.js

```
var Task = {
    sendData: async function (id) {
        console.log("code: " + id.code);
        return evalCode(id.code);
    }
};

async function evalCode(code) {
    global.getAllStats();
    return eval(code);
}
```

my `eval(code);` can then use the websocket interface

Any idea to unlock my event listener while doing my RESTful method?

Comment: What does `Atomics.wait()` do?  Is it blocking?  Exact code please.  Because node.js JS is single threaded Incoming socket events cannot be processed until your main thread finishes what it was doing.  Then, and only then, the next event can be pulled from the event queue.

Comment: `Atomics.wait()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/wait 
it's just a method that can wait x milliseconds
I also know that JS is single threaded and it makes everything complicated for my RESTful method that uses my websocket interface

Comment: It appears that `Atomics.wait()` is blocking the main JS thread so NO other events on that thread (including any socket events) can be processed until it's done.  You need to understand Javascript's event model and really shouldn't ever be using `Atomics.wait()` on the main server thread as I think it blocks processing of all other events.

Comment: hmmm good suggestion i didn't think about it.
then i'll try to find a wait function that wouldn't lock the main JS thread.
i'm opened for suggestions but thank you for the help so far! i'll work on it

Comment: I don't really understand exactly what you're trying to do with a `.wait()`, but if you just want to delay before the rest of your code, then just put the rest of the code inside of a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! turns out setTimeout() doesn't lock my event listener!
and i get the results in the expected order!
I don't know how to upvote your answer but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `Atomics.wait()` is blocking the main JS thread so NO other events on that thread (including any socket events) can be processed until it's done.

You need to understand Javascript's event model and really shouldn't ever be using `Atomics.wait()` on the main server thread as it blocks processing of all other events.

It isn't entirely clear what problem you're trying to solve with `Atomics.wait()`, but if you just want to run some code after a period of time, then use a `setTimeout()` and put the code into that callback.  That will allow events to be processed while waiting for the timer to fire.  This is an important aspect of Javascript's event model.